# How do I return firstchild value in LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, linq

Using LINQ, How do I only get the author element value for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<quotes>
  <category name="Sport">
    <author>James Small
      <quote>Quote One</quote>
      <quote>Quote Two</quote>
    </author>
  </category>
  <category name="Music">
     <author>
      Stephen Swann
     <quote />
    </author>
  </category>
</quotes>
```

I'm new to LINQ but I've tried

```
   Dim quotesXMLList As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = From n In q.Descendants("category") _
                                                   Select n
    For Each n In quotesXMLList

        authorList.Add(n.Value)
    Next
```

but n.value returns the author and all the child element values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns all the author names:

```
var authorNames =
    from category in q.Elements("category")
    from author in category.Elements("author")
    from textNode in author.Nodes().OfType<XText>()
    select textNode.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will safely retrieve the first child:

```
list.Where(x => x.Children.Any()).Select(x => x.Children.First());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life easier by changing your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<quotes>
  <category name="Sport">
    <author>
      <name>James</name>
      <quote>Quote One</quote>
      <quote>Quote Two</quote>
    </author>
  </category>
  <category name="Music">
     <author>
      <name>Stephen</name>
     <quote />
    </author>
  </category>
</quotes>
```

You can then get the names with:

```
var nodes = 
from item in xdoc.Descendants("name")
select new {author = item.Value};
```